# Get the windows 2010 command prompt for python precompiled libraries

Tags: python, mod-wsgi, precompiled

While this isn't a direct programming question, it's something that has been bothering me for quite some time. And keeps annoying me to no end, and I expect others also have this problem.

On windows quite a few libraries require you to use a precompiled version (numpy, pyqt, mod_wsgi). Now these precompiled versions require often you to have installed the correct C-compiler, the one used for python 3.4 is VC10. This compiler corresponds with  visual studio 2010.

Now some (mod_wsgi as explained [here](https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/mod_wsgi/tree/develop/win32)) use further build steps to finalize the library. To do this one should "open the VS 2010 command prompt". Which is included in (free) VS 2010 express.

However googling and further links lead to microsoft' site for [visual studio](https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs). But there only 2015 (or 2013) is available.

So how to finalize the build process (ie the last steps for mod_wsgi) on windows? Can I use VS 2015 command prompt without breaking things? I doubt I can?

Are we basically stuck until python updates to a newer version of visual studio?

Comment: Do you ask if the VS 2015 command prompt will work with VC10 or if it is possible to compile mod_wsgi for python 3.4 using VC14 (VS2015)?

Comment: @Holt Well the former would be "easiest", as that means I/we can use that for any other library in the future. But the latter would also solve problems (though that would mean it is a per-case base).

Comment: I cannot directly solve your problem but: The VS xxxx command prompt is basically a simple command prompt where you have custom environement variables that you can set calling `vcvarsall.bat` (in the your VS installation folder). You can find lots of precompiled libraries on [this site](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/). And last, python 3.5 uses VC14 (VS2015) so you can use the one available online if you want.

Comment: @Holt thanks, but will it correctly use the VC2010 redistributable to compile? - As only the redistributable is capable of being "find" on the internet atm. As for 3.5: that's still not an option by a long shot, many libraries have not updated (apache for example only gives VC11 as newest).